# When to use DataBinding with SQL in WPF

Tags: sql, wpf

I have a table in SQL that I want to read into a DataGrid. 
When I insert a new element I would like the DataGrid to update automatically.
Currently I manually do a SQL query and create a custom object that represents the objects in my SQL.

I am wondering whether I could use DataBinding but also maintain some control over how the data is read in? Because I'd like to have a local model to work with. Or is it just simpler to manually redownload the table after every insert?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. Using Entity framework, to pull the data, and then bind it to a control (or a complex form with many tabs) - and allowing the EF to do all the hard work for You is the way to go ...

Just imagine - if You have a complex model with a lot of controls, and when You hit save.. it just does that and generates as many inserts or updates for you.

with just one line of code. Context.SaveChanges :)